# How to bind JQuery Datatable with list through ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, datatables

I am trying to bind multiple jquery datatable with single ajax call.  Below is code snippet.

How do we bind jquery datable when list is inside class.

Ajax call will return  "ReportViewModel".  List which is required to bind datatable will inside this ReportViewModel object.

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
public List<ReportingDataViewModel> AList { get; set; }
public List<ReportingDataViewModel> MList { get; set; }
public List<ReportingDataViewModel> ACList { get; set; }
}
public class ReportingDataViewModel
{
public string CN { get; set; }
public string RUrl { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
public string StartTime { get; set; }
public string EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

Ajax call will return "ReportViewModel"

```
"processing": true, // for show progress bar
"serverSide": false, // for process server side
"filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
"orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
"ajax": {
"url": "/Reports/GetReports",
"type": "POST",
"datatype": "json",
 
},
"columnDefs": [{
"targets": [0],
"visible": false,
"searchable": false
}],
```

how to access data.Alist to bind datatable.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try console.log() the result that's returned so you can see the structure?  You can do that in the success clause of your AJAX call.

Comment: _How to bind_: It depends on the structure of your JSON. But you typically use the [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to do that, by pointing it at the array where your row data is located in the JSON. _How to populate multiple DataTables from one call_: Assuming each table needs a different subset of the JSON data, then I would use jQuery `ajax` to populate a local variable first (instead of using the DataTables `ajax` option). But that is a bit of a guess, without seeing more information (the JSON, your tables...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo you could follow:

View:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>cn</th>
            <th>rUrl</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>startTime</th>
            <th>endTime</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

JS:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        var columns = [];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Reports/GetReports",
                type:"POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    columnNames = Object.keys(data.aList[0]);
                    for (var i in columnNames) {
                        columns.push({
                            data: columnNames[i],
                            title: columnNames[i]
                        });
                    }
                    $('#example').DataTable({    
                        "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                        "serverSide": false, // for process server side
                        "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
                        
                        "data": data.aList,
                        "columns": columns
                    });
                }
            });                            
        });           
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Reports/GetReports")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    var data = new ReportViewModel()
    {
        ACList = new List<ReportingDataViewModel>()
        {
            new ReportingDataViewModel(){CN="AC_CN1", RUrl="AC_RUrl1",StartTime="2019-8-9", EndTime="2019-8-13",Status="Good"},
            new ReportingDataViewModel(){CN="AC_CN2", RUrl="AC_RUrl2",StartTime="2019-9-4", EndTime="2019-9-15",Status="Nice"},
            new ReportingDataViewModel(){CN="AC_CN3", RUrl="AC_RUrl3",StartTime="2019-8-3", EndTime="2019-8-5",Status="Ok"}
        },
        AList = new List<ReportingDataViewModel>()
        {
            new ReportingDataViewModel(){CN="ACN1", RUrl="ARUrl1",StartTime="2019-3-9", EndTime="2019-3-13",Status="Nice"},
            new ReportingDataViewModel(){CN="ACN2", RUrl="ARUrl2",StartTime="2019-4-4", EndTime="2019-4-15",Status="Nice"},
            new ReportingDataViewModel(){CN="ACN3", RUrl="ARUrl3",StartTime="2019-5-3", EndTime="2019-5-5",Status="Ok"}
        }
    };
    return Json(data);
}
```

Result:

[image]